# How do I use IIFE for this functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iife

I have the following JavaScript:

```
function operation() {
  var ans = document.getElementById("answer");
  if (document.getElementById("add").checked) {
    ans.value = calculate('add');
  }
  if (document.getElementById("subtract").checked) {
    ans.value = calculate('subtract');
  }
  if (document.getElementById("multiply").checked) {
    ans.value = calculate('multiply');
  }
  if (document.getElementById("divide").checked) {
    ans.value = calculate('divide');
  }
}

function calculate(action) {
  var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  var result;
  switch (action) {
    case 'add':
      result = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
      break;
    case 'subtract':
      result = num1 - num2;
      break;
    case 'multiply':
      result = num1 * num2;
      break;
    case 'divide':
      result = num1 / num2;
      break;
  }
  return result;
}
```

And I have a compute button in HTML with `id="theButton`. Then I get the answer with:

```
document.getElementById("theButton").addEventListener("click",operation);
```

But How do I use IIFE for the code above and return the answer accordingly?

Comment: The point of an IIFE is to execute a function immediately without giving it a name. That doesn't apply here, because you don't want to execute the function immediately, you want to execute it when the button is clicked.

Comment: You could put an anonymous function in the `addEventListener` argument, but not an IIFE.

Comment: This looks like it should work fine? What issue are you having and why do you think an IIFE would help you solve that issue?